# Pywinauto search for text on webpage and click on link

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am looking how to automate searching for text on a page and then clicking on a link with pywinauto.

Example: open page lingscars.com and search for text "mirage" and click on that link.

I can open the page, but looking for how to find text and then click on it.

```
from pywinauto import application
import time
import sys

app = application.Application().start("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe https://www.lingscars.com/")
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need more than python for that.

Selenium is the key for this where you want to control your browser.

Basic info is given here --> https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-python-click-buttons-on-websites

But you would need to invest sometime on selenium before you can make it click a single button.

Happy Learning.